# df showing wrong disk usage - disk corrupted

Tags: centos6, software-raid, mdadm, df

I'm getting a rather odd result from df from one of my disks using mdadm. It's setup as 4 of 2TB disks in raid 10.

```
# df
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2              3.6T   40G  3.4T   2% /  <------ this one
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0              4.9G  189M  4.4G   5% /boot
```

The actual disk usage is roughly around 2TB. Yet, it's reporting only 40GB of usage.

I see some errors like this in /var/log/messages as well as /var/log/dmesg (same ones)

```
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24449: 0 blocks in bitmap, 32768 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24450: 3 blocks in bitmap, 32771 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24451: 6 blocks in bitmap, 32766 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24452: 50 blocks in bitmap, 32742 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24453: 43 blocks in bitmap, 32768 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24454: 30 blocks in bitmap, 32768 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24455: 77 blocks in bitmap, 32768 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24456: 27 blocks in bitmap, 32744 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24457: 68 blocks in bitmap, 32265 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: EXT4-fs error (device md2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy: EXT4-fs: group 24458: 32 blocks in bitmap, 1804 in gd
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: JBD: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = md2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: JBD: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = md2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Feb 13 05:46:00 las kernel: JBD: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = md2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
```

But unsure what to make of it.

mdadm detail shows...

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.1
  Creation Time : Thu Oct 18 22:20:38 2012
     Raid Level : raid10
     Array Size : 3896783872 (3716.26 GiB 3990.31 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1948391936 (1858.13 GiB 1995.15 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

  Intent Bitmap : Internal

    Update Time : Wed Feb 13 05:58:12 2013
          State : active
 Active Devices : 4
Working Devices : 4
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

           Name : i2274.userdns.net:2
           UUID : f64e69c7:8342cdd1:0a275bbf:3ba052f4
         Events : 275873

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
       1       8       18        1      active sync   /dev/sdb2
       2       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       3       8       49        3      active sync   /dev/sdd1
```

Lastly, I just ran fsck by `echo y > /forcefsck` and `reboot`, but seems nothing have changed. I think the disk is corrupted, but uncertain how to proceed.

Comment: Does /forcefsck cause a FULL fsck?  If not then you might be right things are still corrupt.

Comment: `/forcefsck` forces a full fsck, it appends on a `-f` to the fsck command like, verified per `/etc/rc.sysinit` on centos 5

Comment: You should boot off of a rescue disk and `fsck` by hand, interactively it might ask you if it should do some potentially unsafe fixes that it would bypass in non-interactive mode. Backups are a must.

Comment: What filesystem? Directly on `md0` or on a partition on it? Any comments by S.M.A.R.T.? Any fallout in `/var/log/messages` or its neighbors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to bring closure to this issue, I had it do a complete fsck, like @kormoc suggested, in non-interactive mode on boot. This has resolved the issue.